# Is $f$ also necessarily of bounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, bounded-variation

> Let $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function. Define $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}~$ by $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$ and $$f(x)=\frac 1x {\int_0 ^x g(t)~dt} $$ otherwise. Is $f$ also necessarily of bounded variation?

My thought was to try to prove that $f$ is increasing (which is even stronger), but the problem is it might not be true. [For example, if $g(x)=x-10$ , we have $f(0)>f(1)$] .

Now, I see that $f$ has to be increasing on $(0,1]$. So far so good, but this  still doesn't convince me that $f$ is of bounded variation.

Comment: A near counter-example is $g(x)=\operatorname{Ei}(x)+\exp(x)$ where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), but it is $-\infty$ at $0$ !

Comment: Are you interpreting an extended real-valued function like $g(x) = -1/\sqrt{x}$ for $0 < x \leqslant 1$ and $g(0) = - \infty$ to be an |\"increasing function" defined on $[0,1]$?  Excluding such things the claim is true.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly $f$ is increasing on $(0,1]$ -- as you say (but have not shown) -- since $g$ is increasing and for $0 < x < y \leqslant 1$ we have

$$\begin{align}f(y) - f(x) &= \frac{1}{y} \int_0^y g(t) \, dt - \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x g(t) \, dt \\&= \frac{1}{y} \int_x^y g(t) \, dt - \frac{y-x}{xy}\int_0^x g(t) \, dt \\ &> \frac{1}{y} \int_x^y g(x) \, dt - \frac{y-x}{xy}\int_0^x g(t) \, dt \\ &= \frac{y-x}{y}g(x) - \frac{y-x}{xy}\int_0^x g(t) \, dt \\ &= \frac{y-x}{xy}\int_0^x (g(x) - g(t)) \, dt\\ &> 0\end{align}$$

To say that $g$ is **defined and increasing** on the closed interval $[0,1]$ implies that $g$ is bounded. Thus, for $0 < x \leqslant 1$

$$|f(x)| \leqslant \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x |g(t)| \, dt \leqslant \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |g(t)|, $$

and since $f(0) = 0$ we have that $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and increasing on $(0,1]$ which implies it has bounded variation.